# Cómo ejecutar un switch para imprimir la masa corporal

Tags: java

Cómo ejecutar un switch para imprimir la masa corporal según la siguiente tabla:

```
IMC Hombres | IMC Mujeres | Estado
------------|-------------|-------------- 
Menor a 20  | Menor de 20 | Bajo Peso 
20 a 24.9   | 20 a 23.9   | Normal 
25 a 29.9   | 24 a 28.9   | Obesidad Leve 
30 a 40     | 29 a 37     | Obesidad Severa 
Mayor de 40 | Mayor a 37  | Obesidad muy severa
```

Éste es mi código:

```
import java.awt.; import java.applet.; import java.awt.event.; import java.math.;

public class masaCorporal extends Applet implements ActionListener { TextField tfEstatura,tfPeso;//entradas de texto Label lEstatura,lPeso;//label de los textos de entrada Button boton; Checkbox generom,generof; double IMC; //variable para mostrar el resultado //método constructor,donde se crean los objetos a dibujar en el applet public masaCorporal() { //Damos la instruccion que no se usará ningun layout para poder dibujar con setBounds this.setLayout((null));

//setBounds(posicionx, posiciony, ancho, alto) lEstatura= new Label("Estatura (mt): "); lEstatura.setBounds(20, 20, 100, 20); lPeso= new Label("Peso (kg): "); lPeso.setBounds(20, 40, 100, 20); tfEstatura = new TextField(); tfEstatura.setBounds(120, 20, 100, 20); tfPeso = new TextField(); tfPeso.setBounds(120, 40, 100, 20); generom = new Checkbox("hombre"); generom.setBounds(120,60,100,20); generof =new Checkbox("mujer"); generof.setBounds(120,80,100,20); boton = new Button("Calcula"); boton.setBounds(120,100,100,20);

//agregamos los elementos a la pantalla

add(lEstatura); add(lPeso); add(tfEstatura); add(tfEstatura); add(tfPeso); add(generom); add(generof); add(boton); boton. addActionListener(this); // se le añade al boton la facilidad de // ser escuchado

} //método paint en el cual se pone lo que se quiere dibujar public void paint(Graphics g) { this.setSize(300, 300);

g.drawString("Su Indice de Masa corporal es = "+IMC, 40, 140); //dibuja el cuadrado } // método para realizar las opciones al oprimir un botón public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { double peso = Double.parseDouble(tfPeso.getText()); double altura = Double.parseDouble(tfEstatura.getText()); double IMC =(peso /(altura *altura));

}
}
```

El error que tengo es que me dice al ejecutar que `el double no se puede convertir en boolean`

Comment: Y qué problema tiene tu código?

Comment: no me imprime  el resultado  , y no me permite realizar el switch , me  sale un error que dice  que el double no se puede convertir  en boolean

Comment: Del código que muestras, ¿en qué línea ocurre el error que dices?

Comment: serias tan amable de arreglar tu codigo para que se entienda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el tipo de datos double corresponde a números reales y el tipo de datos boolean solo permite true o false, esto significa que un numero no puede transformarse en true o false, según el error que indicas, revisa tu código, atento a cualquier consulta.